# Fetching Images

Tags: android, arrays, json, parsing

In an Android Application - I am sending a Json String like this

```
{"restarutant":{"name":"Chung Wah","photo":"http:\/\/i.imgur.com\/AnXB0.jpg","address":"93, 2ndc ross, GDP etx.","area":"Vylaikaval","city":"Bangalore","location":["13.015621","77.277531"],"phone":["9986377561","08023467969"],"rating":"4","cuisines":["Chinese","Korean"],"attributes":["smoking","parking","delivery"],"gallery":["http:\/\/i.imgur.com\/9THuR.jpg","http:\/\/i.imgur.com\/05Oon.jpg","http:\/\/i.imgur.com\/fPm96.jpg","http:\/\/i.imgur.com\/sICp4.jpg","http:\/\/i.imgur.com\/JP8mG.jpg"]}}
```

This is a result of an array below (just to understand how the array is formated)

```
    $restaurant = array('restarutant' => 
array('name' => 'Chung Wah', 
      'photo' => 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/AnXB0.jpg', 
      'address' => '93, 2ndc ross, GDP etx.', 
      'area' => 'Vylaikaval', 
      'city' => 'Bangalore', 
      'location' => array('13.015621', '77.277531'),
      'phone' => array('9986377561', '08023467969'), 
      'rating' => '4', 
      'cuisines' => array('Chinese', 'Korean'), 
      'attributes' => array('smoking', 'parking', 'delivery'),
      'gallery' => array('https://i.stack.imgur.com/9THuR.jpg', 
                         'https://i.stack.imgur.com/05Oon.jpg',
                         'https://i.stack.imgur.com/fPm96.jpg', 
                         'https://i.stack.imgur.com/sICp4.jpg',
                         'https://i.stack.imgur.com/JP8mG.jpg')
));
```

Now when the Activity Loads. Which is the best way to download these Images from the Server and Display ?

Whats the procedure we need to follow ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Lazy load of images in ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/541966/android-how-do-i-do-a-lazy-load-of-images-in-listview) - the best start point for you to download images asynch into views.